# The shape and __len__ of an array return 4 when there is only 1 row?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, dimensions

After preforming an `np.loadtxt()` of a CSV file I see the following results based on the file containing only 1 row of data.

```
dcsv: [ 45.29625588 -75.92420601  64.66075832   2.25      ]
dcsv shape: (4L,)
dcsv type:  float64
DataSet Length dcsv: 4 Rows
```

I don't know, why it thinks there are 4 rows of data. It recognizes that there are 0 rows and 2 rows or more but returns 4 when there is only 1.

**Example of 2 rows:**

```
dcsv: [[ 45.29638366 -75.92428038  64.8255732    1.        ]
       [ 45.29638376 -75.92427927  64.82507261  13.        ]]
dcsv shape: (2L, 4L)
dcsv type:  float64
DataSet Length dcsv: 2 Rows
```

**Example of 0 rows:**

```
dcsv: []
dcsv shape: (0L,)
dcsv type:  float64
DataSet Length dcsv: 0 Rows
dcsv = []
dcsv = np.loadtxt('Start5SecondsSIMPy2JS.csv',delimiter=',',skiprows=0,usecols = (0,1,2,3)) 
print "dcsv:", dcsv
print "dcsv shape:", dcsv.shape
print "dcsv type: ", dcsv.dtype
print "DataSet Length dcsv:",dcsvLen,"Rows"
```

Providing a solution will be greatly appreciated.

I need the solution to work with 0,1,2.....10,000+ rows. Both np.atleast_2d & ndim produced a result of 1 with 0 rows and 1 row. My solution is to use the np.size, which returned a 0 for 0 rows and a 4 for 1 row, and either of these methods which allows me to discern a file with 0 rows or with 1 row. Any number of rows >= 2 will be handled by np.ndarray.len.

Comment: If you want the shape to be (1, 4), use the argument `ndmin=2`.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, `numpy.loadtxt` defaults to squeezing length-1 axes instead of preserving the row-column structure of the input. You can specify `ndmin=2` to preserve the structure:

> **ndmin** : *int*, *optional*
>   The returned array will have at least *ndmin*
>   dimensions. Otherwise mono-dimensional axes will be squeezed. Legal
>   values: 0 (default), 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

The `__len__` method of a `numpy.ndarray` returns the length of the first dimension. In your case the shape is `(4L, )` and therefore `len` or `__len__` will return `4`.

If you want to add a dimension you could, for example, specify that the array should be [`atleast_2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html):

```
>>> dcsv = np.atleast_2d(dcsv)
```

Comment: 0 rows produces: dcsv shape: (1L, 0L) & DataSet Length dcsv: 1 Rows while 1 row produces: dcsv shape: (1L, 4L) & DataSet Length dcsv: 1 Rows.  Any thoughts why?

Comment: I think it's because 0 rows are interpreted as `np.array([[]])`. What would you expect for a `shape` and `#rows` in that case? In theory it gives an expected output: Found 1 row with 0 columns.... :-]